# ReferenceError: Vue is not defined heroku laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, heroku

hi i have finished my laravel project locally all it works well, i use vuejs and also jquery, i host my project in a heroku, and i find some error, especially in vuejs `"ReferenceError: Vue is not defined"` and also in system validation `"Class App \ Http \ requests \ srequest does not exist"`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` after the migration to remote host.

Comment: No, don't so `npm install` on Heroku. You'll just get a one-off dyno that loses any changes you make to it.